# Firebase distinct clause

Tags: firebase

I have records in my table but I want to get 1 for each duplicate.

For example,

1. Kato,  support@firebase.com, August, 001
2. Oladapo,  oladapoadebowale@gmail.com, August, 002
3. Kato, support@firebase.com, March, 001
4. Oladapo, oladapoadebowale@gmail.com, April, 002
5. Liyah,  liyah@firebase.com, June, 003

So I want a query that will give

1. Kato,  support@firebase.com, 001
2. Oladapo,  oladapoadebowale@gmail.com, 002
3. Liyah,  liyah@firebase.com, 003

The query only picked one of the duplicate using the id. Somewhat like sql distinct clause

Thanks

Comment: If you are talking about string values, you don't actually have any duplicates in your example. The string   'Kato, support@firebase.com, August, 001'  is not a duplicate of   'Kato, support@firebase.com, March, 001'.  Are you wanting any to query for any string that has Kato in it? Or 001? Or are those stored as separate values? (if they are not, they should be).

Comment: @Jay, I want to get the [name] where the id = [num], so in the case of Kato, it will return two records which is normal but I want it return just one since those records are of the same person. So I want to get "Kato, 001"

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jay,  I fix it by making the first data unique by giving it a field clone:0 then all subsequent data with such Id will have clone:1

All I now do is to get all data with clone:0

Thank you for showing interest.